# Vimscript file rewrites itself and complains of a mismatched endfor

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript

I want to remap `<C-i>*character*` to `i*character*<Esc>` for easy inserting of single characters. This is what I've written:

```
let printable_characters = [ '!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', '''', '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '[', '\', ']', '^', '_', '`', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '{', '|', '}', '~']
for val in printable_characters
    silent! execute "nnoremap <C-i>" . val . " i" . val . "<Esc>"
    silent! execute "nnoremap <C-a>" . val . " a" . val . "<Esc>"
    unlet val
endfor
```

When I try to source it by executing `:source %`, the following happens:

1. It will complain about how I forgot the `endfor`
2. Once I press return, the file will look like this:

   ```
   let printable_characters = [ '!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', '''', '(',          ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '[', '\', ']', '^', '_', '`', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '{', '|', '}', '~']
   for val in printable_characters
       silent! execute "nnoremap <C-i>" . val . " i" . val . "<Esc>"
       silent! execute "nnoremap <C-a>" . val . " a" . val . "<Esc>"
       unlet val
       silent! execute "nnoremap <C-a>" . val . " a" . val . "<Esc>"
       unlet val
       endfor
   endfor
   ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a much better way of accomplishing this than brute forcing it.  You can use these simple expr mappings instead:

```
nnoremap <expr> <c-i> "i" . nr2char(getchar()) . "<Esc>"
nnoremap <expr> <c-a> "a" . nr2char(getchar()) . "<Esc>"
```

Here is how they work:

- `nnoremap <expr> <c-i>` - Create a mapping for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> with the `<expr>` flag.  This flag tells vim to interpret all of the characters after `<c-i>` as an expression when the mapping is triggered, which means you can use functions, variables, operators and the like.
- `"i" . nr2char(getchar()) . "<Esc>"` - A simple expression which concatenates `"i"`, a single character given by the user, and `"<Esc>"`.  `getchar` returns a number representing the pressed key, so `nr2char` is used to convert it to a string.  The result of this concatenation is what is used as the final mapping when the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>.  For example, if the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> then this expression evaluates to `"it<Esc>"`, which then results in those keys being pressed.

For more, see `:help :map-<expr>`.

Also, look at the other answers for why your current solution doesn't work.

Comment: This works wonderfully, thank you very much!

Answer (score 7):

One of your "printable" characters is a vertical bar, `|`. When that value comes up in your loop, you effectively execute:

```
nnoremap <C-i>|i|<Esc>
```

The bar denotes the end of the map command (see `:help map_bar`). You probably want to escape it in the array, like `'\|'` (or choose another method of generating these mappings).

(You can observe this by reducing, temporarily, your printable characters array to just `[ '|' ]` or alternatively by removing `'|'` from your set and seeing the behavior change.)

Answer (score 6):

To include a pipe or bar (<kbd>|</kbd>) in a map, use `<bar>`. A literal `|` will end the `map` command and take what follows as a new command. That means that the `execute` command does something very different from what you intend when `val == '|'`. The *different* involves all the characters trailing the pipe, although I'm not sure at a glance exactly why you get this particular effect.

If you comment out the loop and variable assignment, replace the concatenation with a literal `|`, and source the file you will see a similar effect:

```
" let printable_characters = [ '!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', '''', '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '[', '\', ']', '^', '_', '`', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '{', '|', '}', '~']
" for val in printable_characters
    silent! execute "nnoremap <C-i>|i|<Esc>"
    silent! execute "nnoremap <C-a>|a|<Esc>"
    " unlet val
" endfor
```

becomes

```
" let printable_characters = [ '!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', '''', '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '[', '\', ']', '^', '_', '`', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '{', '|', '}', '~']
" for val in printable_characters
    silent! execute "nnoremap <C-i>|i|<Esc>"
    silent! execute "nnoremap <C-a>|a|<Esc>"
    " unlet val
    silent! execute "nnoremap <C-a>|a|<Esc>"
    " unlet val
" endfor
" endfor
```

See `:help map_bar`.

Comment: I read [this](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/26.html) which said, that `'` is the only character that has a special meaning in literal strings, which lead to my own confusion, thank you very much!